# Python Boto3 script shows duplicate output

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I have recently updated my code wrapping the for loop into a function, also utilising click to accept an input which acts as a variable when searching for particular values in tag:environment.

The problem I have is that the print under def(main) is outputting the correct total (in this case 4), but the results are all the same.

i.e InstanceID, State, PrivateIpAddress, InstanceType, Name -- repeated 4 times with the same information

To test that both the dict and list have the correct information I added print(ec2_info) or print(ec2_details) into def get_instance_info and this shows correctly.

This is my code :

```
import boto3
import click

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')



def get_instance_info(env):
    
    ec2_details = []
    ec2_info = {}

    get_stuff = ec2.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'tag:environment',
                    'Values': [env]
                }, ] )
    
    for reservation in get_stuff['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            ec2_info.update({'InstanceID':instance['InstanceId']})
            ec2_info.update({'State':instance['State']['Name']})
            ec2_info.update({'PrivateIpAddress':instance['PrivateIpAddress']})
            ec2_info.update({'InstanceType':instance['InstanceType']})
            for tag in instance['Tags']:
                if tag['Key'] in 'Name':
                    ec2_info.update({'Name':tag['Value']})
        ec2_details.append(ec2_info)
       
       
    return ec2_details

  
@click.command()
@click.option('--env', '-e', required=False, help='Environment Tag Name')

def main(env):
    ec2_details = get_instance_info(env)
    

    if ec2_details:
        print(ec2_details)
    else:
        print('There are no results')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: ec2 info shoule be reset in the for statement not the outside.

Comment: @Lamanus Many thanks for the pair of eyes. Rehashed it and working as expected with new formatted print output.